# Interpolation code with MapBasic

Tags: interpolation, mapbasic, vertical-mapper

I have drivetest data, and usually I do an interpolation using the values taken in the drive with their respective lat/long. I use natural neighbor. You can see an example attached.

[image]

I am trying to automate the process; however, in MapBasic, I cannot find any resource of a code to do that. I found something interesting which is vertical mapper, but it is like the GIS -> Grid Analysis in PlanetEV and I can't find a way.

Has someone tried to do this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few suggestions for doing grid interpolation with MapInfo Pro/MapBasic

**No add-ons**

In MapInfo Pro without add-ons gridding is part of the thematics. But you only have a few interpolation methods to pick from, TIN and IDW.

To get a look at the MapBasic code, try creating a Gridding Thematic using MapInfo Pro or have a look at the Create Grid statement in the MapBasic help files.

**Vertical Mapper**

Vertical Mapper is the gridding tool used for decades with MapInfo Pro. Vertical Mapper also comes as a SDK giving you the opportunity to write your own gridding application.

Vertical Mapper has been and still is used in a broad variety of industries from telecom to engineering companies.

**Discover**

Discover has been developed by the Australian company Encom, now part of Pitney Bowes, with a main focus on the exploration and mining industry. Discover has however also been adopted widely within other areas such as geotechnical companies and public sector.

Discover, however, doesn't come with a SDK so you are not able to create your own applications.

**MapInfo Pro Raster x64**

The new kid in town is called MapInfo Pro Raster. So far Pitney Bowes has only released a beta release but the first release is expected late April or early May.

The first version is focused on importing and working with existing grid files. The second release later this year will also be able to interpolate new grids.

Also notice that MapInfo Pro Raster is a 64 bit application that requires MapInfo Pro 64 bit to work.

We also release a .NET based SDK for MapInfo Pro Raster. This will make it possible for you to create your own grid application, either as a stand-alone tool or as an add-on for MapInfo Pro x64.

If you want to get started with the .NET SDK for MapInfo Pro Raster, have a look at this article: [Developer Dojo: Getting started with the MapInfo Pro Raster API](https://li360.pitneybowes.com/s/article/ka180000000DBKrAAO/Developer-Dojo-Getting-started-with-the-MapInfo-Pro-Raster-API)

Comment: Peter, this is very useful. Great sharing! I'll try working out with Vertical Mapper even though the SDK CreateGrid functions are somehow tough.. Ill post updates on that. CheerS! @Peter

Comment: Peter, I am asking you this again because I am getting to a solution. I got my hands on Vertical mapper; however, using the dll VmNatNeigh.dll in Visual studio is not possible. Im not being able to use it. Is there a different way ? Cheers @peter

Comment: @Karl, unless you have strong feelings for Vertical Mapper, I would strongly recommend that you take a look at the new MapInfo Pro Advanced that include MapInfo Pro Raster. Included is also a .NET SDK which makes it possible to automate tasks using, for instance .NET/Visual Studio.

Comment: I will try mapinfo pro advanced. Should I use v15.2 ? Or is there a trial version? I prefer trying it first and making sure it works before buying it. What do you think?

Comment: @Karl, install the trial version of MapInfo Pro 15.2 which also includes MapInfo Pro Advanced. You might have to activate the Advanced trial separately on the HOME tab. Get it here: http://www.pitneybowes.com/us/miprov15-2.html

Comment: Peter, do you know how to ask the user to open a table and then when they browse a table, it takes it in the code? 

For example: "open a table" 
then the user can browse a location and enter it. 

Is it possible? or it has to be stated in the code and not dynamic?

@Peter

Comment: I think that is a new question, Karl, but look at the function FileOpenDlg() :-)